# Using the same object in two different classes

Tags: java, class

Is there a way of accessing a single object in two different classes ?

Lets say i have a class

```
public class A{
MyClass myObj = new MyClass();

myObj.setValue(x);
}
```

Is there a way of using `myObj` in another class, say class `B` and being able to access the value that is set i.e `x` without having to create `getX` methods in  class `A` ?

Comment: You don't pass round objects, you are passing references to an object and that reference can be repeated as many times as you like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You can make the object static...

```
public class A{
 public static MyClass myObj = new MyClass();

 myObj.setValue(x);
}
```

This can be accessed from anywhere vis A.myObj

Having said that, I don't prefer using static too much. Use only if it's absolutly necessary.

You use a static variable when the stored data is associated with a class, and a non-static one when it's associated with an object.

Answer (score 0):

Could pass it into the constructor of B.

```
public class B {
    MyClass obj;

    B(MyClass obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }
}
```

So `new B(myObj);` then just call `myObj.getValue();`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean this

```
public class A{
int x; int y;
}

public class B{
A a; int b;
}
```

then Yes. This is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set x to be *public* / *package-scoped* etc ([here's the Java tutorial on access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)), but I really wouldn't advise that.

Why don't you want a `getX()` accessor ? It's a decent practice since it's promoting encapsulation, and your implementation of `x` (do you have a direct reference ? do you calculate it on the fly ? do you load it lazily from a cache ?) can change in the future *without having to modify all the client classes*. If you access `x` directly, then you're directly exposing your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So create the object once, and pass it into the constructors of A and B:

```
C c = new C();
A a = new A(c);
B b = new B(c);

...

public class A 
{
    private final C c;

    public A(C c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```